# Sharepoint 2013 On Premise - Break inheritance on a secondary wiki pages library

Tags: 2013, wiki-pages, sharepoint-server

I'm working in the support team for SP 2013 On Premise and I'm a bit stuck on an issue that a user raised.

The structure of the site collection is:
- parent site (used by multiple departments)
- sub-site (with unique authorizations to only one department)
- in the sub-site above there are 2 wiki pages libraries: one should inherit the same authorizations as the sub-site, the other one should have unique permissions.

When trying to break inheritance on the 2nd wiki pages library it works, but whatever group I delete or add to the library authorizations, it's mirroring in the sub-site authorizations too, as if the break inheritance feature didn't work.

Now I'm currently giving unique authorizations per each page in the 2nd library, individually, but it is a bit of a struggle because it's not 1-2 pages, there are a lot of them. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Any ideas would be great!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce this issue. In my environment(15.0.4569.1000), the permissions changes made in the second library only affected on the library, not the subsite-level.

You can have a test on other subsite to check if this issue only occurs on the special site. If this issue also occurs on other sites, you can check the build number of your farm, and try to update your farm to the latest one, then test again.